# How to connect Sybase from client tool for password Encrypted db

Tags: sap-ase

Our back end Sybase db password encryption is enabled and for this I am unable to connect the db using any client tool. here is the exception:

```
Error connecting to datasource "UAT"
```

SQL Error [1640] [S1000]: Adaptive Server requires encryption of the login password on the network.

SQL Error [4002] [S1000]: Login failed
SQL Error [4002] [S1000]: Login failed.
    Adaptive Server requires encryption of the login password on the network.

From java/ property file I ma bale to connect using below properties
ENCRYPT_PASSWORD=true
JCE_PROVIDER_CLASS=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried isql (the command line tool) to confirm if your connection details are correct?

The basic command would be:
`isql -U username -S servername -X`

This will help determine if it is something more fundamental that is causing the problem.